# mdadm build legacy array on boot

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mount, software-raid, fstab

I have RAID0 that was built using windows dynamic disk. I've read that this is a legacy array and can be assembled using build in mdadm. I've gotten the array to build and mount using the following commands:

```
sudo mdadm --build /dev/md0 --chunk=64 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdb1
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/md0 /media/raid
```

This works great!

Now I'm working on getting this array to mount on boot. I've added the following entry to fstab:

```
 /dev/md0 /media/raid ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0
```

This is where my problem arises. Before md0 can be mounted though, it needs to be assembled. Everything I've read says to run the following:

```
sudo mdadm --detail --scan
```

And to put the output into mdadm.conf. However the output is:

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=
```

Since the array is legacy, it does not have a uuid or any meta-data, and mdadm can't build it solely off `ARRAY /dev/md0` in the conf file.

What should I put into mdadm.conf in order for the raid to be assembled in legacy mode on boot?

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be done automatically via mdadm.conf. However you can make a script with the correct mdadm command and have it run on boot (either from `/etc/rc.local` or from `/etc/init.d` - ideally before the mounting of all filesystems start).

Comment: I added my two original commands to an init.d script and it successfully mounts now. Thanks! I am still curious if there is a way to mount a legacy raid with mdadm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `mdadm.conf` specifies arrays for assembly, it can be used only for "normal" arrays and not legacy ones. The manpage states that for legacy arrays (build mode):

> This usage is similar to --create.  The difference is that  it 
>   creates an array without a superblock. With these arrays there is no
>   difference between initially creating the array and  subsequently 
>   assembling  the array,  except  that hopefully there is useful data
>   there in the second case.

So these arrays are not assembled. I guess this is because there is no way of checking if the array has been built successfully. `mdadm` in this case only makes the new device without care on what data are on those original devices.

The solution for you is to build the array on boot using a script in `/etc/init.d` (or `/etc/rc.local`) which will be called before all fstab filesystems get mounted.

You can try this line in `mdadm.conf`, but I don't think it will work: `ARRAY /dev/md0 level=0 devices=/dev/sdc1,/dev/sdb1`